# Installing maven on Ubuntu by manual download

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

To install Maven, I downloaded the latest version from the website and then followed these steps:

http://maven.apache.org/download.html#Installation

The last step, the version control, does not work. It says that 'mvn' is currently not installed and that I should type `sudo apt-get install maven2`

If I go directly to the mvn file itself, it does work:

```
root@ubuntu:~# /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/mvn --version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 12:16:01-0700)
Java version: 1.6.0_21
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.32-25-generic" arch: "i386" Family: "unix"
```

So, what am I doing wrong here? Or what would and apt-get install do extra that I might have forgotten?

Answer (score 1):

Add the manually installed maven binary-directory to your PATH-environment

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue on 11.10, this is how I solved it:

1. Install Maven2 from Synaptic rather than downloading it from the website.
2. `gedit ~/.bashrc` and check if you have `M2_HOME` and `M2` env variables defined if so DELETE them, delete them from `PATH` too, if there is a reference to them.
3. Reload bash and `trymvn --version` again.

Answer (score 0):

possibly its not in your path the program mvn?

or if mvn is referring to a package maybe ubuntu doesn't know about your tar non deb install?